# How to integrate bitcoin payment in ASP.Net?

Tags: bitcoind, payment

I am new to Bitcoin. How to integrate Bitcoin payment into my one of website which is designed using ASP.Net.

Also how to test it using Sandbox mode as provided by other gateways like PayPal?

Regards

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to integrate with a 3rd party bitcoin payment provider you can implement your own payment module for Bitcoin (but also for Litecoin and every Bitcoin-derived altcoin) very easily with **[BitcoinLib](https://github.com/GeorgeKimionis/BitcoinLib)** that is written in C#.

Some of **[BitcoinLib](https://github.com/GeorgeKimionis/BitcoinLib)**'s features:

- Fully compatible and up-to-date with Bitcoin 0.9.1 RPC API.
- Design-by-contract, service-oriented architecture.
- Strongly-typed structures for complex RPC requests and responses.
- Implicit JSON casting for all RPC messages.
- Extended methods for every-day scenarios where the built-in methods fall short.
- Exposure of all RPC API's functionality as well as the extended methods through a single interface.
- Fallback mechanism for timed-out RPC requests.
- Custom RPC exceptions.
- Supports all Bitcoin clones.
- Can operate on unlimited daemons with a single library reference.
- Litecoin integration included.
- Each coin instance can be fully parametrized at run-time and implement its own constants.
- Console test client with demo methods implemented in it.
- Disconnected raw RPC connector included for quick'n'dirty debugging.
- Testnet ready.
- Fully configurable.

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to bitcoin, just for accepting payments it is recommended to use a service like [BitPay](https://bitpay.com/) or [BIPS](https://bips.me/)

They will provide

- Easy API - as opposite of bitcoind API which is intended for low level bitcoin tasks. If you are familiar with PayPal moving to other payment providers should be easy.
- Fiat to bitcoin currency and vice versa
- Address generation and matching orders to their bitcoin payments

Working with bitcoind directly from a web developer perspective is a little cumbersome, so I don't recommend it if you lack bitcoin experience.

Answer (score 0):

You can use open source bitcoin/altcoin package from gourl.io:

https://github.com/cryptoapi/Bitcoin-Payment-Gateway-ASP.NET

It works fine in my project.